# Upload data through mobile network - Objective C

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, phone-call

In my app, I'm trying to upload some data when the user receives some phone calls. So, is it possible to upload data through GSM data network either when a phone call comes or while the phone call is in progress? Thanks.

Comment: are you trying to record the calls and send data to you? As per info I have, we can use internet if you have 3G or higher version of internet

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `CTCallCenter` class in the `Core Telephony framework` to register an event handler so your app gets notified when a call starts or ends and there you can do whatever you want.

The CTCall gives the following callState property

`CTCallStateDialing`

`CTCallStateIncoming`

`CTCallStateConnected`

`CTCallStateDisconnected`

Hope it helps you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add CoreTelephony framework at your project.

Try the following code. It will give you clear understanding of the flow.

```
#import <CoreTelephony/CTCall.h>
#import <CoreTelephony/CTCallCenter.h>

static CTCallCenter *callCenter;

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_window release];
    [_viewController release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];



    if([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 4.0)
    {
        callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
        callCenter.callEventHandler=^(CTCall* call)
        {
            NSLog(@":: Call id:%@",call.callID);
            if (call.callState==CTCallStateDialing)
            {
                NSLog(@":: Call state:dialing");

            }
            if (call.callState==CTCallStateIncoming)
            {
                NSLog(@":: Call state:incoming");
            }
            if (call.callState==CTCallStateConnected)
            {
                NSLog(@":: Call state:Connected");                
            }
            if (call.callState==CTCallStateDisconnected)
            {
                NSLog(@":: Call state:Disconnected");
            }
        };
    }


    return YES;
}
```